# Apply imageTransform on twitter media feed

Tags: image-transforms, plugin-imager, plugin-dukttwitter

```
  {% set response = craft.twitter.get('statuses/user_timeline', { tweet_mode:'extended', count: 20 }) %}
            {% if response.success %}
            {% for tweet in response.data %}
            {% if tweet.extended_entities.media is defined %}
            {% for item in tweet.extended_entities.media if item.type == 'photo' %}

            <div><img src="{{ item.media_url.getUrl('footerThumbs') }}" alt=""/></div>
            {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
```

This throws a Runtime error: Impossible to invoke a method ("getUrl") on a string variable ("http://pbs.twimg.com/media/DlAIWwkUcAAY_3u.jpg").

What other method is possible?

Using the Imager plugin:
{% set externalImage = 'http://pbs.twimg.com/media/DlAIWwkUcAAY_3u.jpg' %}

```
{% set transformedImages = craft.imager.transformImage(externalImage, [
                { width: 200, height: 200 }])
              %}
         {% set response = craft.twitter.get('statuses/user_timeline', { tweet_mode:'extended', count: 20 }) %}
            {% if response.success %}
            {% for tweet in response.data %}
            {% if tweet.extended_entities.media is defined %}
            {% for item in tweet.extended_entities.media if item.type == 'photo' %}

            <div><img src="{{ externalImage }}" alt=""/></div>
            {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Craft's built-in transform functionality doesn't support transforming external URLs. You could use my [Imager plugin](https://github.com/aelvan/Imager-Craft) to do this instead.

EDIT:

Based on your example, you'd use Imager something like this:

```
{% set response = craft.twitter.get('statuses/user_timeline', { tweet_mode:'extended', count: 20 }) %}
{% if response.success %}
    {% for tweet in response.data %}
        {% if tweet.extended_entities.media is defined %}
            {% for item in tweet.extended_entities.media if item.type == 'photo' %}
                {% set transformedImage = craft.imager.transformImage(item.media_url, { width: 200, height: 200 }) %}
                <div><img src="{{ transformedImage.url }}" alt=""/></div>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

So, the essential part is that you need to pick up the url to each item in the loop (`item.media_url`, if that's what the twitter plugin returns), and do the transform inside the for loop.

Comment: I knew there was a way of achieving this. I've even used this before, but couldn't think of what it was called. Gonna add this to my list of regular use plugins.

Comment: @André, I did try implementing your plugin Imager, which works great for a single image (knowing the absolute path) but how do you find the path for multiple tweet (image) entries? See added code in the original question.

Comment: @Nutmeg I've updated my reply.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware it's not possible, because the Twitter feed APIs are fed a URL path to the asset on Twitter's server. So Craft never handles the actual asset to be able to crop it.

I'm sure the P&T guys or Andrew that usually respond to questions will have a suggestion, but I don't think it's really possible.

Best you can do it crop images in CSS using `object-fit: cover` in a div the size you want the image to be.

EDIT:

But the actual error you're getting is because `item.media_url`is a string for 'http://pbs.twimg.com/media/DlAIWwkUcAAY_3u.jpg', so it doesn't have a url to access with `.getUrl`.

I'm unsure if it'll work, but you could try `item.media_url('footerThumbs')`

Cheers

Comment: thank you, but I did try that. The solution will be in the Imager plugin, but the question is how....

Comment: I haven't used it for a long time unfortunately. Looks like Andre above is helping you. Good luck!